# parseClass loadClass groovy

Tags: groovy

When using the `GroovyClassLoader`, when should I use `loadClass` and when should I call `parseClass`?

If I understand it, the first call to `loadClass()` will compile the script, and subsequent calls will use the cached class file rather than recompiling it.

But what about `parseClass` then?

Comment: I edited your question to try and make it readable.  Did I keep the question the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation for `parseClass`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html#parseClass%28java.io.File%29) shows that it takes a File or a String containing Groovy code, and converts it into a class.

If the function is passed a File, then the GroovyClassLoader will cache this generated class, but if it is passed a String, it [will not cache it](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.java#L201).

The function `loadClass` (from [the documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean%29)) says:

> loads a class from a file or a parent classloader.

What it basically does, is looks for the class already existing in the classLoader, and if it fails to find it, look for the script file on disk with the matching name.

Once this class is loaded, it will be cached.  The next time you call `loadClass`, it will use this cached class *unless* you pass `false` for the `preferClassOverScript`.  If you pass `false`, it will attempt locate the script on disk again, [recompile the class](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.java#L678) if necessary.